# Vercel deployment build failed (MongoDB/API Call)

Tags: mongodb, next.js, deployment, vercel

**Please check the Error message below:**

[image: View Error Message from Vercel]

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(`https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/api/posts`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}
```

Code runs just fine locally (when replaced `${process.env.VERCEL_URL}` with `localhost:3000`, but the error happens when trying to deploy on Vercel.

I have env file set to save mongodb URI, and the VERCEL_URL is a Vercel's prefixed environment variable.

Seems like some others have had same issues, but I can't figure out how to resolve the issue after trying some solutions out there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.